# Expected Value: from $\mathbb{E}( A \vert X, Y )$ to $\mathbb{E}(A \vert X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can I calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}(A \vert X)$ if I know $\mathbb{E}( A \vert X, Y )$ and X,Y are not independent and discrete? Which probability $p_?(?)$ do I need  for this?

$\mathbb{E}(A \vert X) = \sum_{i,j} \mathbb{E}( A \vert X=x_i, Y=y_j ) p_?(?)$

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to condition on $Y$.

$\mathbb{E}(A \vert X) = \sum_{i,j} \mathbb{E}( A \vert X, Y=y_j ) p(Y=y_j\vert X)$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, don't you need something like $\mathbb{E}(A \vert X) = \sum_{j} \mathbb{E}( A \vert X, Y=y_j ) p(Y=y_j|X) \;$?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I missed it.