# Law of total expectation: $\mathbb{E}( X | A )$ and $p_{A|B}(a|b)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I've got a question regarding the law of total expectation and conditional probabilities.

Assuming I know the EV: $\mathbb{E}(X | A)$ and the PDF $p_{A|B}(a|b)$ (A,B are not independet but binomially distributed).

What is then the outcome of 
$\sum_{dom(A)} \mathbb{E}(X | A) ~p_{A|B}(a|b) $ ?
Is it $\mathbb{E}(X | B)$?

Comment: Is this an offshoot of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889030), posted under a different user name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have said something like $$\mathbb{E}(X | B=b) =\sum_{a \in dom(A)} \mathbb{E}(X | A=a, B=b) \;\Pr(A=a|B=b)$$ and this is not necessarily the same as your expression unless  $\mathbb{E}(X | A=a, B=b)=\mathbb{E}(X | A=a)$, which would be the case if $X$ and $B$ were [conditionally independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given $A$.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm a bit confused, because in [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851924/expected-value-from-mathbbe-a-vert-x-y-to-mathbbea-vert-x), the answerer suggest to use $Pr(A=a)$ in the sum, if there is a 'double' conditioning in the expected value. I would appreciate if you could clarify on that. Thanks.

Comment: For that question I would have had something like $\mathbb{E}(A \vert X) = \sum_{j} \mathbb{E}( A \vert X, Y=y_j ) p(Y=y_j|X) \;$

Comment: Ok :-). Thanks once again. Unfortunately I don't have sufficient reputation to upvote your answer and comment. But I will do so once I have.